# Passing a table to client

Tags: jdbc, javafx, client-server, javafx-2

I have to build a client/server database; the server builds the database that contains a single table. It has to pass the table to
the client which will display it in a `TableView`.
The server retrieves the SQL commands from a txt file.
The question is how do I (Server) pass the table that I've created to the client?
I thought of `ArrayList` but it gets really complicated and hard to handle.
The server code:

//Load driver, connect to JDBC..

```
  private void DBSetup()
  {
      try
      {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("mysql.txt");
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
           //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
           { 
            System.out.println(strLine);

            //INSERT PLATFORM->RUNLATER
            status.appendText(strLine+"\n");

            if (strLine != null && !strLine.equals("")) 
                statement.execute(strLine);          
           }
        br.close();
      }catch (java.lang.Exception ex)
        {
            Platform.runLater(()->
            {
            status.setText(ex.toString());
            });
        }

  }
```

My program supports multiple clients, so I have a hashTable that holds the socket and the outputStream of each client.
P.S.: I'm working with javaFX.

Comment: Your server code should really know nothing of how the client handles the data; i.e. it should be independent of JavaFX. Typically you would have an entity class, instances of which represent a single row in the table. Your JDBC code can fairly easily create a `List` of those entities. You can then stream that to the client any way you like (JSON, or even just Java object serialization if you want to be "old school"). `Platform.runLater(...)` makes no sense at all on the server; there is no JavaFX thread running there.

Comment: Thanks. I only posted what I thought is relevant to the question, the server does show a UI where you type the user/pass.
I saw an example using RowSet but it's part of Swing.
Do you think I can use a more dynamic structure besides a list/arraylist?
Thanks again.

Comment: Your question is too broad to be reasonably answered on StackOverflow bio.  There are a million and one ways for a client to get data from a server.  Raw sockets as you seem to be using is not really one I would recommend because it is a lower level abstraction than you need.

Comment: Choose a client/server communication mechanism, e.g., [RestEasy](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/rest-services-using-javafx-tutorial), [spring remoting](http://www.zenjava.com/2012/02/25/going-remote-javafx-and-spring-remoting/), [websockets](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test) or [akka](http://akka.io) or [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/). Try implementing it, and post back with very specific questions (and ideally minimal, executable sample code) when you run into issues.

Comment: I'm following a specific design where I'm only allowed to use raw sockets. The problem I'm facing here is how to send the table that I've built from a txt file, how to send the columns and the rows, taking in consideration that I don't know the name of the table (Imported from the file).